# Safari 6: Open and close tabs with middle click?

Tags: macos, tabs, safari

On Lion I installed an extension which game me the ability to use middle click to open and close tabs, and I used Better Touch Tool (BTT) to use a 3 finger tap to act as a middle click.

Since using Mountain Lion DP4, and subsequently the final release with Safari 6, I am only able to open tabs with a middle click, and I have to use keyboard shortcuts or by clicking on the tab close X.

Is there anything which will give me middle click to close a tab which works on Safari 6 under Mountain Lion available now?

Comment: I've temporarily added a 4 finger tap which maps to CMD+W in BTT for Safari, but it's not the best solution as sometimes I accidentally close tabs, I know I can easily open them again with CMD+Z so it's OK, but I'd still prefer a tap to close on the tabs themselves if anyone knows a way.

Comment: Your best option is to look for a new extension/app or see if there are any plans to update the ones you're currently using. They will probably soon be updated for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up the same 3 finger middle click gesture in BTT and it works great with [Glims for Safari](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims)'s middle click to close setting.

Comment: Ahhh Glims, that was the name of it! I'd completely forgotten, and it's the one I had before that I was looking for :)

Comment: FYI, Safari 6 support is so far only in dev builds: http://wiki.machangout.com/howdoi/glims-development-build

Comment: The new release of Glims (6th of August) now supports Safari 6. v1.0 build 34 :)