# Is there still some way to get scroll wheel functionality on the Marble Mouse with macOS today?

Tags: high-sierra, mouse, macos, karabiner

[image]

I have a Logitech Marble Mouse that I was hoping I could use with a Mac. [It used to be that you could use KeyRemap4Macbook,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98508) known later as [Karabiner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229839), to allow you to hold a button down and turn the trackball into a scroll wheel. However, since Karabiner became Karabiner-Elements, it doesn't seem to have the mouse options it used to, and this method is no longer possible.

I used to use a utility on Windows called [Marble Scroll](https://sites.google.com/site/marblescroll/) (which eventually became abandonware but someone else made another [with the same name](https://www.fewprojects.com/marblescroll-for-logitech-trackman-marble/)), and Linux has functionality in evdev that allows you to do this natively.

The closest workaround I've found so far is with Grab Scroll in [Smart Scroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html), but that doesn't send actual scroll wheel signals, it only scrolls - so some applications won't support it properly, like with alt+scroll wheel zoom in Photoshop. It also stops scrolling when the cursor hits a screen edge.

So, on macOS High Sierra or later, is there any way to give this trackball proper scroll wheel behavior?